# codeiginter upload and resize

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, continuous-integration

I have a problem with CI class image, image does not resize...

for example :

controller

```
private function _do_upload(){
    $config['upload_path']        = 'upload/';
    $config['allowed_types']      = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']           = 1000; //set max size allowed in Kilobyte
    $config['max_width']          = 1000; // set max width image allowed
    $config['max_height']         = 1000; // set max height allowed
    $config['file_name']          = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload('photo')) //upload and validate{
         $config2['image_library']   = 'gd2';
         $config2['source_image']   = $this->upload->upload_path;
         $config2['create_thumb']    = TRUE;
         $config2['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
         $config2['width']           = 450;
         $config2['height']          = 500;

         $this->load->library('image_lib', $config2); 

         if(!$this->image_lib->resize()){
             $data['inputerror'][] = 'photo';
             $data['error_string'][] = 'Upload error: '.$this->upload->display_errors('','');
             $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }
        return $this->upload->data('file_name');   
   }else{
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'photo';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Upload error: '.$this->upload->display_errors('',''); //show ajax error
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();
   }
}
```

But i got no error, I dont know where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have a few issues...

**1.** You have commented out your opening `{` which would break your code.

> if($this->upload->do_upload('photo')) //upload and validate {

Should be

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('photo')) { //upload and validate
```

**2.** The next part: If you do have a resize error you are not doing anything with your messages... So...

```
     if(!$this->image_lib->resize()){
         $data['inputerror'][] = 'photo';
         $data['error_string'][] = 'Upload error: '.$this->upload->display_errors('','');
         $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }
```

Needs the added json_encode like..

```
     if(!$this->image_lib->resize()){
         $data['inputerror'][] = 'photo';
         $data['error_string'][] = 'Upload error: '.$this->upload->display_errors('','');
         $data['status'] = FALSE;
         echo json_encode($data);
         exit();
    }
```

In reference to your resizing, you do need to supply the images full filename and not just the path where "files" live...

Your source_image is a Path to where the files are uploaded to. Not the Path/Filename of the image you want to resize...

```
$config2['source_image']   = $this->upload->upload_path;
```

So if you add this line that gives you the full path and filename and use it...

```
$file_data = $this->upload->data();
$config2['source_image']   = $file_data['full_path'];
```

Does that work better?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have to fix but still pictures can be uploaded but can not resize, I do not know where the mistakes of others?

Comment: thank you TimBrownlaw my web has been running successfully